# document.onmousemove not firing over a embedded pdf object

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-chrome

I have a PDF document embedded in div in a page. The page also has re-sizable regions to make one column smaller/larger than another on demand.

When re-sizing the regions, onmousemove events are not fired when the mouse is over the pdf, thus breaking a lot of the re-size functionality.

Any way to get these onmousemove events?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up overlaying a div on top of the PDF.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of.

One option is to replace the embedded PDF with a placeholder (a `<div>` for example, same dimensions as embedded PDF) during dragging. So, when the `mousedown` event fires, hide the PDF, show the placeholder. When the user has finished dragging show the PDF again.

Comment: +1 good workaround, if you must use embedded PDFs (the horror!)

Comment: Ouch. That's a good suggestion though, thanks. I'll wait a bit longer before marking as answered.

Comment: Maybe just draw an invisible overlay on top of the embedded pdf, so that the events are fired on the overlay and not on the embedded pdf; no need to actually hide the pdf. But do ensure that the overlay is removed in the end! (User will get angry and confused because your site "broke the pdf".)

Comment: If I go with this method though, I will probably just hide it rather than replace the node.

Comment: Just an FYI, I tried overlaying a div with style: "pointer-events: none", but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: @JIP Because click events are ignored when an element has 'pointer-events: none'. I thought that this might trick the body in to getting mouseevents, since the mouse would then be over the div and not the pdf, but it didn't.